# Verb for "to share an environment"

Tags: verbs

I was just wondering if there is a verb for "to share an environment"; the word needs to depict how a non-indigenous organism can share an environment with an indigenous organism in harmony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [sym•bi•o•sis](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/symbiosis) (ˌsɪm biˈoʊ sɪs, -baɪ-)
>
> n., pl. -ses (-sēz).
> 1.
> a. the living together of two dissimilar organisms, as in mutualism, commensalism, or parasitism.
> b. (formerly) mutualism.
> 2. any interdependent or mutually beneficial relationship between two persons, groups, etc.
> *[1615–25; < Greek symbíōsis=symbiō-, variant s. of symbioûn to live together (sym- sym- + bioûn to live) + -sis -sis]*
> sym`bi•ot′ic (-ˈɒt ɪk) sym`bi•ot′i•cal, adj.
> sym`bi•ot′i•cal•ly, adv.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbiosis

Where symbiosis could either be parasitic or invasive upon a host that is not the original or natural habitat of the invading party. It could also be mutual.

Symbiosis is a term also frequently used in computer systems management or programming, in organisational management, or in equipment and manufacturing processes.

One could also be a **symbiotic sibling** with another occupant of the host or environment. Which means, both occupants share the same symbiotic host or environment.

Answer (score 1):

Cohabit?

(Stack Exchange complains if I enter less than 30 characters.)

Answer (score 1):

If I were talking about organisms I would use **coexist**.